# How do statically-typed languages deal without generics?

Tags: generics, language-design, static-typing

I'm curious which statically-typed languages have no generics support
(and to a lesser extent which languages historically did not have generics), and how they deal with it.

Do users just cast all over the place?  Is there some special sauce for basic collections, like lists and dictionaries, that allow those types to be generic?

Why do these languages not have generics?  Is it to avoid potential complexity or other reasons?

Answer (score 2):

C—and historical C++, before it was called C++—requires you to either manually expand "generic" types into non-generics (i.e. the C preprocessor macro equivalent of C++ templates) or escape the type system (i.e. void pointers).

However, arrays (lists) are treated as composite types rather than a single type.  You can have an array of shorts, for example, but you could not treat it the same as an array of chars or even of longs.

This isn't a really big problem in C, though inconvenient at times.  It does represent a trade-off from 40 years ago, to put it in context.

Answer (score 1):

Download java 1.4 or 1.3 and try it yourself.

**Hint**: Yes there will be probably many casts

**How to deal:** I've seen an organization forcing any API not to use collection (in the method declaration) but array to avoid confusion to the user. Alternative is to create a specific collection classes that only works with certain class for example `StringList` etc

Comment: "I've seen an organization forcing any API not to use collection (in the method declaration) but array to avoid confusion to the user." Yes I did that in Java 1.4 and before. If there was no special reason to use a `List` I would rather use `MyObj[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this is C++ templates. Unlike generics, which restrict existing types, templates are a way of generating new types at compile time. Like most code-generating solutions, it's not a very satisfactory one: hence we have moved on.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough to say this with certainty but I believe generics are a way to create new types(maybe you are expressing the view that java generics compile to casts from/to Object and just constrain your code to only allow type safe casting(not including non compiler casting and runtime/reflection tricks) , I think this is sort of the wrong way to think about it as opposed to java generating types at compile time and type checking(generic programming) and then throwing some of the type information out, (again this should be vetted by people who know this stuff well).

Comment: Also I am fairly sure that generics are a subset of c++ template usage.

Comment: You are mistaken on all these counts. (i) Generics do not generate code at compile time or any other time, ergo they do not create new types at any time. Ergo 'generating types' is the wrong way to think about it. (ii) Generics have several features that C+ templates do not have, e.g. 'super' and 'extends' and ?, so they cannot possibly be a subset.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal, in its original forms, did not support generics.  If you wanted a linked list, you needed to make one for your specific type (e.g. IntLinkedList).

Modern versions of Pascal (e.g. ObjectPascal/Delphi) may provide some form of generics.

Answer (score 0):

C# didn't support generics until v2.0. So yes, then you needed a lot of casting from `Object`.

I guess the same goes for VB.Net.